# On Block Click Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-router-redux

I have a container that is a set of buttons, but let us just observe the component as a single component. This component has an `onBlockClick` which receives the `id` for where to go.

I would like to transform `id` to be a `registrationSomeContainer`.

My problem is, how can I address other container from the `onBlockClick`?

```
let registrationContainer = ({
    i18n,
    id,
    name,
    representative,
    onBlockClick,
    dispatch
}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <div
                className="app_wrapper"
            >
                <Block
                    leftIcon="close"
                    lines={[
                        "Some",
                        representative
                    ]}
                    onBlockClick(id)
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: could you clarify the use case? by "to transform id to be a registrationSomeContainer", what do you mean?

Comment: I have a block button and I want to jump to other container when I click on it.

Comment: I am not sure to entirely understand your use case but you should have a parent react component with a state like `{currentBlock: 1}`. Each children Block should have a unique identifier and compare it to `currentBlock` to be displayed or not. `onBlockClick` must actually be called with an id as parameter to update the parent state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A less performant way is**

```
const registrationContainer = ({
    i18n,
    id,
    name,
    representative,
    onBlockClick,
    dispatch
}) => {
    return (
        <div className="app_wrapper">
            <Block
                leftIcon="close"
                lines={[
                    "Some",
                    representative
                ]}
                onBlockClick={onBlockClick.bind(null, id)}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**A more optimized Code could be**

```
const registrationContainer = ({
    i18n,
    id,
    name,
    representative,
    onBlockClick,
    dispatch
}) => {
    return (
        <div className="app_wrapper">
            <Block
                id={id} // Look: passing id
                leftIcon="close"
                lines={[
                    "Some",
                    representative
                ]}
                onBlockClick={onBlockClick} // Look: not binding
            />
        </div>
    );
}

class Block extends Component {
    handleClick = (e) => {
        this.props.onBlockClick(this.props.id);
    };

    render() {
        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>

        </div>
    }
}
```

**Why is binding the bad way**

Binding `onBlockClick={onBlockClick.bind(null, id)}` makes `onBlockClick`get new reference everytime so caused the children component to re render. Read more from here https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Comment: But if I have other `registrationSomeContainer` how can I jump to that one?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want?

Comment: I want to go to a specific container when I click on the button, since I have a set of buttons that will go to different containers each other.